# Testing Realm under Android

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, realm

I have an application for Android where I use Realm to persist data. I now want to write a unit test for this application, utilizing Realm.

However, I do not want the unit test to interfere with my existing Realm data. So I want to generate different Realm files for my test Instance. I don't care if they have a different name, or are stored in a different directory.

I have tried to use a `RenamingDelegatingContext`, but with no success. According to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/realm-java/WyHJHLOqK2c/WJFYvglIGk0J `getInstance()` only uses the `Context` to call `getFilesDir()`, which does not seem to be overwriting the `getFilesDir()` method, so I end up using my live data for testing.

Next I tried to use `IsolatedContext`, but `IsolatedContext.getFilesDir()` returns `null`, so this also was not successful.

Finally, I tried to write a class extending `RenamingDelegatingContext`, overwriting `getFilesDir()`, return a different directory for Realm to use. I created the directory using the DeviceMonitor of AndroidStudio, but when I try to use this context, Realm fails with an `io.realm.exceptions.RealmIOException: Failed to open . Permission denied. open() failed: Permission denied`.

Does anyone know if there is a possibility to test Realm without affecting live data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was actually quite blind, with the solution being quite easy by just using a different name for the RealmDatabase during test setup while generating its configuration. My solution now looks as follows:

```
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(getContext()).
        schemaVersion(1).
        migration(new CustomMigration()).
        name("test.realm").
        inMemory().
        build();
Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are using JUnit4 you can use the TemporaryFolder rule to generate a test folder: https://garygregory.wordpress.com/2010/01/20/junit-tip-use-rules-to-manage-temporary-files-and-folders/

```
@Rule
public TemporaryFolder testFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

@Test
public void testRealm() throws IOException {
    File tempFolder = testFolder.newFolder("realmdata");
    RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(tempFolder).build();

    Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(config);
    // Do test
    realm.close(); // Important
}
```

Comment: I'm currently using JUnit3, so this does not seem usable for me. I solved my issue by using a different database file with the ConfigurationBuilder, but I will keep your solution in mind, since it seems actually a little bit better because it also deletes the temporary files after testing

Comment: @Christian
 Tried above code with Junit4 getting following exception on getInstance() :
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no realm-jni in java.library.path
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1865)
 at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
 at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
 at io.realm.internal.RealmCore.loadLibrary(RealmCore.java:117)

Comment: Currently Realm does not support testing on the JVM, you need to run the tests on a device.

Comment: is there any better way to write unit test for realm queries , other than mocking response of every small function ??

Comment: @ChristianMelchior can you explain me please what's the difference between usage of temporary folder rule and setting realm instance as inMemory in this case

Answer (score 2):

A minor alternative to using [`setDefaultConfiguration`](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/Realm.html#setDefaultConfiguration-io.realm.RealmConfiguration-) might be to [directly use `Realm.getInstance`](https://medium.com/@q2ad/android-testing-realm-2dc1e1c94ee1) in `@BeforeClass`:

```
RealmConfiguration testConfig = 
   new RealmConfiguration.Builder().
      inMemory().
      name("test-realm").build();

Realm testRealm = Realm.getInstance(testConfig);
```

and [inject the `testRealm` into your classes](http://misko.hevery.com/attachments/Guide-Writing%20Testable%20Code.pdf).