# Realm Unit Testing

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, realm, powermockito

I am trying to unit test Realm and its interactions but things are not going too well. I have included all dependencies and keep getting vague failures, below is my code for the `Helper` class which is a wrapper over `Realm`.

Questions

1. Is this the correct way of testing Realm?
2. How can I test data that is in the app's sandbox, can that data only be tested by UI/Instrumentation tests?
3. I am getting an error currently (below) and before I was getting a "Powermock zero args constructor doesn't exist"

[GitHub repo](https://github.com/Zohaib-AHussain/RealmUnitTesting)

Below is the current code I have for my Unit test:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 21, application = CustomApplicationTest.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({"org.mockito.*", "org.robolectric.*", "android.*", "javax.crypto.","java.security.*"})
@SuppressStaticInitializationFor("io.realm.internal.Util")
@PrepareForTest({Realm.class, RealmConfiguration.class,
    RealmQuery.class, RealmResults.class, RealmCore.class, RealmLog.class})
public class DatabaseHelperTest {

@Rule
public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();

private DatabaseHelper dB;

private Realm realmMock;


@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    mockStatic(Realm.class);
    mockStatic(RealmConfiguration.class);
    mockStatic(RealmCore.class);
    mock(DatabaseHelper.class);

    final Realm mockRealm = PowerMockito.mock(Realm.class);
    realmMock = mockRealm;

    final RealmConfiguration mockRealmConfig = PowerMockito.mock(RealmConfiguration.class);

    doNothing().when(RealmCore.class);
    RealmCore.loadLibrary(any(Context.class));

    whenNew(RealmConfiguration.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockRealmConfig);
    when(Realm.getInstance(any(RealmConfiguration.class))).thenReturn(mockRealm);
    when(Realm.getDefaultInstance()).thenReturn(mockRealm);

    when(Realm.getDefaultInstance()).thenReturn(realmMock);

    when(realmMock.createObject(Person.class)).thenReturn(new Person());

    Person person = new Person();
    person.setId("2");
    person.setName("Jerry");
    person.setAge("25");

    Person person2 = new Person();
    person.setId("3");
    person.setName("Tom");
    person.setAge("22");

    List<Person> personsList = new ArrayList<>();
    personsList.add(person);
    personsList.add(person2);

    RealmQuery<Person> personRealmQuery = mockRealmQuery();
    when(realmMock.where(Person.class)).thenReturn(personRealmQuery);

    RealmResults<Person> personRealmResults = mockRealmResults();
    when(realmMock.where(Person.class).findAll()).thenReturn(personRealmResults);
    when(personRealmResults.iterator()).thenReturn(personsList.iterator());
    when(personRealmResults.size()).thenReturn(personsList.size());

    when(realmMock.copyFromRealm(personRealmResults)).thenReturn(personsList);

    realmMock = mockRealm;
    dB = new DatabaseHelper(realmMock);
}


@Test
public void insertingPerson(){
    doCallRealMethod().when(realmMock).executeTransaction(any(Realm.Transaction.class));

    Person person = mock(Person.class);
    when(realmMock.createObject(Person.class)).thenReturn(person);

    dB.putPersonData();

    verify(realmMock, times(1)).createObject(Person.class);
    verify(person, times(1)).setId(anyString());
}


@Test
public void testExistingData(){
    List<Person> personList = dB.getPersonList();
    //NPE if checking person object properties i.e name, id. Only list size is available why?
    Assert.assertEquals(2, personList.size());

}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private <T extends RealmObject> RealmQuery<T> mockRealmQuery() {
    return mock(RealmQuery.class);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private <T extends RealmObject> RealmResults<T> mockRealmResults() {
    return mock(RealmResults.class);
}
```

Error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: 
Argument passed to verify() is of type Realm$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$317bc746 and is not a mock!
Make sure you place the parenthesis correctly!
See the examples of correct verifications:
verify(mock).someMethod();
verify(mock, times(10)).someMethod();
verify(mock, atLeastOnce()).someMethod();

at com.appstronomy.realmunittesting.db.DatabaseHelperTest.insertingPerson(DatabaseHelperTest.java:133)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Comment: Same question with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34343601/powermockito-notamockexception-on-a-mock . Just adding  "org.powermock.*"to the line @PowerMockIgnore...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is this the correct way of testing Realm?

How about following the official tests. While [instrumentation tests seem easy](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/unitTestExample/src/androidTest/java/io/realm/examples/unittesting/jUnit4ExampleTest.java), [unit test are quite involved](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/unitTestExample/src/test/java/io/realm/examples/unittesting/ExampleActivityTest.java):

> ```
> @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
> @PowerMockRunnerDelegate(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
> @Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 21)
> @PowerMockIgnore({"org.mockito.*", "org.robolectric.*", "android.*"})
> @SuppressStaticInitializationFor("io.realm.internal.Util")
> @PrepareForTest({Realm.class, RealmConfiguration.class, RealmQuery.class, RealmResults.class, RealmCore.class, RealmLog.class})
> public class ExampleActivityTest {
>     // Robolectric, Using Power Mock https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/wiki/Using-PowerMock
>
>     @Rule
>     public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();
>
>     private Realm mockRealm;
>     private RealmResults<Person> people;
>
>     @Before
>     public void setup() throws Exception {
>
>         // Setup Realm to be mocked. The order of these matters
>         mockStatic(RealmCore.class);
>         mockStatic(RealmLog.class);
>         mockStatic(Realm.class);
>         mockStatic(RealmConfiguration.class);
>         Realm.init(RuntimeEnvironment.application);
>
>         // Create the mock
>         final Realm mockRealm = mock(Realm.class);
>         final RealmConfiguration mockRealmConfig = mock(RealmConfiguration.class);
>
>         // TODO: Better solution would be just mock the RealmConfiguration.Builder class. But it seems there is some
>         // problems for powermock to mock it (static inner class). We just mock the RealmCore.loadLibrary(Context) which
>         // will be called by RealmConfiguration.Builder's constructor.
>         doNothing().when(RealmCore.class);
>         RealmCore.loadLibrary(any(Context.class));
>
>
>         // TODO: Mock the RealmConfiguration's constructor. If the RealmConfiguration.Builder.build can be mocked, this
>         // is not necessary anymore.
>         whenNew(RealmConfiguration.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockRealmConfig);
>
>         // Anytime getInstance is called with any configuration, then return the mockRealm
>         when(Realm.getDefaultInstance()).thenReturn(mockRealm);
>
>         // Anytime we ask Realm to create a Person, return a new instance.
>         when(mockRealm.createObject(Person.class)).thenReturn(new Person());
>
>         // Set up some naive stubs
>         Person p1 = new Person();
>         p1.setAge(14);
>         p1.setName("John Young");
>
>         Person p2 = new Person();
>         p2.setAge(89);
>         p2.setName("John Senior");
>
>         Person p3 = new Person();
>         p3.setAge(27);
>         p3.setName("Jane");
>
>         Person p4 = new Person();
>         p4.setAge(42);
>         p4.setName("Robert");
>
>         List<Person> personList = Arrays.asList(p1, p2, p3, p4);
>
>         // Create a mock RealmQuery
>         RealmQuery<Person> personQuery = mockRealmQuery();
>
>         // When the RealmQuery performs findFirst, return the first record in the list.
>         when(personQuery.findFirst()).thenReturn(personList.get(0));
>
>         // When the where clause is called on the Realm, return the mock query.
>         when(mockRealm.where(Person.class)).thenReturn(personQuery);
>
>         // When the RealmQuery is filtered on any string and any integer, return the person query
>         when(personQuery.equalTo(anyString(), anyInt())).thenReturn(personQuery);
>
>         // RealmResults is final, must mock static and also place this in the PrepareForTest annotation array.
>         mockStatic(RealmResults.class);
>
>         // Create a mock RealmResults
>         RealmResults<Person> people = mockRealmResults();
>
>         // When we ask Realm for all of the Person instances, return the mock RealmResults
>         when(mockRealm.where(Person.class).findAll()).thenReturn(people);
>
>         // When a between query is performed with any string as the field and any int as the
>         // value, then return the personQuery itself
>         when(personQuery.between(anyString(), anyInt(), anyInt())).thenReturn(personQuery);
>
>         // When a beginsWith clause is performed with any string field and any string value
>         // return the same person query
>         when(personQuery.beginsWith(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(personQuery);
>
>         // When we ask the RealmQuery for all of the Person objects, return the mock RealmResults
>         when(personQuery.findAll()).thenReturn(people);
>
>
>         // The for(...) loop in Java needs an iterator, so we're giving it one that has items,
>         // since the mock RealmResults does not provide an implementation. Therefore, anytime
>         // anyone asks for the RealmResults Iterator, give them a functioning iterator from the
>         // ArrayList of Persons we created above. This will allow the loop to execute.
>         when(people.iterator()).thenReturn(personList.iterator());
>
>         // Return the size of the mock list.
>         when(people.size()).thenReturn(personList.size());
>
>         this.mockRealm = mockRealm;
>         this.people = people;
>     }
>
>
>     @Test
>     public void shouldBeAbleToAccessActivityAndVerifyRealmInteractions() {
>         doCallRealMethod().when(mockRealm).executeTransaction(Mockito.any(Realm.Transaction.class));
>
>         // Create activity
>         ExampleActivity activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(ExampleActivity.class).create().start().resume().visible().get();
>
>         assertThat(activity.getTitle().toString(), is("Unit Test Example"));
>
>         // Verify that two Realm.getInstance() calls took place.
>         verifyStatic(times(2));
>         Realm.getDefaultInstance();
>
>         // verify that we have four begin and commit transaction calls
>         // Do not verify partial mock invocation count: https://github.com/jayway/powermock/issues/649
>         //verify(mockRealm, times(4)).executeTransaction(Mockito.any(Realm.Transaction.class));
>
>         // Click the clean up button
>         activity.findViewById(R.id.clean_up).performClick();
>
>         // Verify that begin and commit transaction were called (been called a total of 5 times now)
>         // Do not verify partial mock invocation count: https://github.com/jayway/powermock/issues/649
>         //verify(mockRealm, times(5)).executeTransaction(Mockito.any(Realm.Transaction.class));
>
>         // Verify that we queried for Person instances five times in this run (2 in basicCrud(),
>         // 2 in complexQuery() and 1 in the button click)
>         verify(mockRealm, times(5)).where(Person.class);
>
>         // Verify that the delete method was called. Delete is also called in the start of the
>         // activity to ensure we start with a clean db.
>         verify(mockRealm, times(2)).delete(Person.class);
>
>         // Call the destroy method so we can verify that the .close() method was called (below)
>         activity.onDestroy();
>
>         // Verify that the realm got closed 2 separate times. Once in the AsyncTask, once
>         // in onDestroy
>         verify(mockRealm, times(2)).close();
>     }
> ```

---

**OLDER ANSWER**

https://medium.com/@q2ad/android-testing-realm-2dc1e1c94ee1 has a great proposal: do not mock Realm, but use a temporary instance instead. Original proposition with dependency injection: Use

```
RealmConfiguration testConfig = 
   new RealmConfiguration.Builder().
      inMemory().
      name("test-realm").build();

Realm testRealm = Realm.getInstance(testConfig);
```

[If dependency injection is not possible, you could use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34280766/1587329)

```
Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(testConfig);
```

instead, which sets the `Realm` returned by `Realm.getDefaultInstance()`.

---

EDIT: If you receive a `java.lang.IllegalStateException`, remember to call `Realm.init(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext())` beforehand, and put the files inside the `android-test` directory. (that is: use an instrumentation test, not a unit test).

Comment: This is not working as it throws exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Call `Realm.init(Context)` before creating a RealmConfiguration`

Comment: `Realm.init(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext())` is not useful when testing  a unit test.

Comment: @serv-inc when adding 'Realm.init(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext())'
it gives me an error 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation.
'

Comment: @serv-inc i was placing in test packages and then i found there exist another package android-test and there exist already example there so i placed the file there and works fine

Comment: Thanks. `mockkStatic(Realm::class)` was just what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

My goal is to test my business logic that depends on Realm. Realm.init kept throwing exceptions like:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Context.getFilesDir() returns /data/user/0/com.pornhub.android.test/files which is not an existing directory. See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36918154
at io.realm.Realm.checkFilesDirAvailable(Realm.java:256)
at io.realm.Realm.init(Realm.java:199)
at com.headcheckhealth.headcheck.GenericRealmTest.<init>(RealmTest.kt:99)
...
```

to get Realm working, use [`getTargetContext()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html#getTargetContext()) instead of [`getContext()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html#getContext()).

```
package com.github.ericytsang

import android.app.Instrumentation
import androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry
import io.realm.Realm
import io.realm.RealmConfiguration
import org.junit.Test

/**
 * tests to see how [Realm] works. nothing domain-specific here.
 *
 * cannot use Robolectric because https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1389 :(
 * need to use Android instrumented tests.
 */
class GenericRealmTest {

    /**
     * [Realm.init] needs [Instrumentation.getTargetContext] to work; [Instrumentation.getContext]
     * will not work.
     */
    private val context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext

    private val db = run {
        Realm.init(context)
        Realm.getInstance(
            RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .inMemory()
                .name("realm.db")
                .build()
        )
    }

    @Test
    fun teardown_works() = Unit
}
```